# Monkeyrunner, how to make device.press multiple times?

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

I have been playing around with monkeyrunner and python/jython and I seem to be finding most of the info I need here so I'm hoping some of the experts can tell me how to make a "device.press" happen multiple times. for the purposes of learning lets say I want to turn the volume all the way down, here is what I've tried so far:

```
device.press("KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN", "DOWN_AND_UP", 8)
```

and

```
device.press("KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN", "DOWN_AND_UP", 8, 8)
```

As you may have guessed on my phone and image it takes 8 presses to get volume all the way down, but neither of those lines worked. Is there a way to do it without repeating the line 8 times? I know I could do it that way but it seems a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

[MokeyDevice.press()](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html#press) takes only 2 arguments, the rest are ignored. It could warn you that you are using the wrong number of argument but it silently ignores them.

The correct way is

```
times = 8
for n in range(times):
    device.press("KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```